# unable to understand what `sh !` does inside a Jenkins pipeline code

Tags: shell, unix, jenkins, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I have a Jenkins pipeline code having

```
stages {
    stage('Monitoring logs') {
       steps {
          script {
              sh '! grep "wow" output.log
                 }
              }
          }
      }
```

Can someone please explain what does this part of the code do -> `sh '! grep "wow" output.log'` and what impact will it have if any on the execution or the status of the pipeline execution incase "wow" string is found in `output.log`?

I understand that `grep "wow" output.log` will search for "wow" string in `output.log` but i dont know what would `sh '! grep "wow" output.log'` do?

Comment: I am not an expert of Jenkins but usually negate option `!` is for omitting/negating the output. So here it means, print the opposite status of `grep` command so if results `wow` found by `grep` it will be `0` but after negating it it will become `1` here(because success status of a command is 0).

Comment: `sh` is an executable for a shell and usually can be found in `/bin`. `'! grep "wow" output.log"` is the command to be run in the shell.

Comment: @AnsFourtyTwo In this case [`sh` is a Groovy function](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-durable-task-step/#sh-shell-script).

Comment: What impact will it  `sh '! grep "wow" output.log'` have on the execution or status of the pipeline in case string "wow" is found in `output.log`? @AnsFourtyTwo  @Biffen  @RavinderSingh13

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. [`grep "wow" output.log`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/grep.html#tag_20_55_14) succeeds (exits 0) if `output.log` contains `wow`, and fails (exits non-0) otherwise.
2. [`!` negates the exit code](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_02) (0 becomes 1; non-0 becomes 0).
3. [Jenkins’ `sh` function](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-durable-task-step/#sh-shell-script) runs a shell script and throws an exception, which will make the pipeline fail, on a non-0 exit code.<sup>*</sup>

Ergo the pipeline will fail if `output.log` contains `wow`.

<sup><sup>*</sup> Through the use of the `-e` option.</sup>